# How to generate QRcode and show in a web Page

Tags: java, zxing

How can i use the "zxing" (http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) or any other library which available on free to generate a QR code and display on my web page.

When user register on my web page providing the information i want to show a qrcode with his/her (name/email/mobile Phone number)

Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your web page is for public access I strongly recomend that you use the Google Charts API. Here is an example:
https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/docs/qr_codes

Comment: I also found this link is doing the same in java code http://www.journaldev.com/470/generate-qr-code-image-from-java-program